# spring data redis data disorder(The value of A should be A, but it becomes B)

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

When I use spring-data-redis, it across one problems.

> keyA = valueA
> keyB= valueB

I want to save these two keys.It's normal at ordinary times.
The following situation will happen in about three months.

> keyA = valueB

I checked my code, but found no problems.
I can't reproduce this problem, so I don't know how to solve it.
maybe my code worng but i'dnot know where and why.How can I solve it?
My Redis Server is 2.8.9 and I am using spring-data-redis version 2.3.2.RELEASE.

```
    @Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxActive);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(minIdle);
    poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(maxWait);
    LettucePoolingClientConfiguration poolClient = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
            .poolConfig(poolConfig)
            .clientName("pool_client").build();
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(database);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(host);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(port);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(password));
    LettuceConnectionFactory factory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, poolClient);
    factory.setShareNativeConnection(false);
    return factory;
}
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(factory);
    ProtostuffSerializer protostuffSerializer = new ProtostuffSerializer();
    StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
    template.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer);
    template.setHashKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer);
    template.setValueSerializer(protostuffSerializer);
    template.setHashValueSerializer(protostuffSerializer);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
}
```

Comment: How to reproduce？

Comment: I found the reason. protostuffSerializer is not thread safe.